# Displaying 2 binary variables over years using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have dataset that consists of 4 variables and about 200k complete observations.

- recordno: ID variable
- year: Year of injury
- txa: binary 0/1, 1 means drug was given
- blunt: type of injury blunt or penetrating, binary

1) I am trying to create a barplot using ggplot2 describing the utilization of the drug for both types of injuries across the years 2013 to 2019. The problem is my Y access is showing wrong counts of the drug as both bars for each type of trauma are maxing out.

2) I am also trying to place a label over each box to show the count. (number of times txa was used during that year)

I appreciate any help. Please see the code below.

```
utilize <- data.frame(txa = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), 
                 year = c("2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019", "2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014"), 
                 blunt=c("blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt", "blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt", "blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt"))

          util2 <- utilize %>% 
  group_by(year, blunt) %>% 
  summarise(txa_total = sum(txa))

ggplot(util2, aes(fill=blunt, y= txa_total, x=year, group = blunt)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=txa_total), color="black", 
            size=3.5, position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
            vjust = -.25)+
  ylim(c(0,2000)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          plot.caption = element_text(face= "italic"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, face= "bold"), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face= "bold"))+
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Type of trauma", values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))+
   labs(x = "Year of Injury",
y = "Count of cases receieving TXA",
title = "TXA Utilization in Trauma Patients in the State of Michigan Between 2013 and 2018",
subtitle= "Plot of number of trauma cases by year",
caption = "Data source: MTQIP 2013-2018")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to transform your data to make this easier. If you are looking for utilization (given/total), but should be an easy change to the summarize call.

```
utilize <- data.frame(txa = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), 
                      year = c("2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019", "2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2019","2013","2016","2017", "2019", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2014"), 
                      blunt=c("blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt", "blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt", "blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt","penetrating","blunt"))

util2 <- utilize %>% 
  group_by(year, blunt) %>% 
  summarise(txa_total = sum(txa))

ggplot(util2, aes(fill=blunt, y= txa_total, x=year, group = blunt)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=txa_total), color="black", 
            size=3.5, position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
            vjust = -.25)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Year of Injury",
       y = "Cases where TXA was administered",
       title = "Utilization of TXA in trauma patient between 2013 and 2019"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but there is a small problem. Not all of the x-axis labels are showing. I adjusted my code above. Thanks